# Моисей простер жезл на море или над морем?

Tags: морфология, предлоги, управление, глаголы, существительные

Вопрос по управлению глагола: простирать *над чем* или *на что*? Из викисловаря: простёрли свой **взор** на землю. Но это со **взором**, а с руками как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

﻿
**простереть**
-стру́, -стрёшь ; простёр, -ла, -ло; простёрший; простёртый, -стёрт, -а, -о; простере́в и простёрши; *сов.* к простирать
**что** *книжн.*
**1) Протянуть, вытянуть в каком-либо направлении.**
*Простере́ть ветви **к** солнцу.

Простере́ть руки **к** небесам* (как воззвание к небесным силам, к Богу).
*Простере́ть свои крылья **под** облаками, **над** горными вершинами* (о птице и самолёте).
*Простере́ть объятия* (протянуть руки для объятия).

[**Словарь многих выражений**](https://all_words.academic.ru/75817)

*И , озарён луною бледной,

**Простерши руку в вышине**,

За ним несётся Всадник Медный

На звонко-скачущем коне.*
Пушкин

*Но вот настал последний миг разлуки.

Чу! Чья-то песнь! Так ангелы поют…

И ты **простер слабеющие руки

Туда наверх**, где странникам — приют.*
М. Цветаева. Людовик XVII

*В день скорби моей Бога взыскал, ночью **простер руки пред Ним** и не был обманут.*
*Тогда Моше поднял свой посох и **простер руку над морем.***
*Клятва пред Господом да будет между обоими в том, что не **простер руки на собственность** ближнего своего...*

1. *Господь **простер жезл свой на грешников**, и разделились грешники по народностям, племенам и родам, верованиям, ересям и расколам.*
   (Направил жезл — куда? на что? — в сторону грешников, на грешников, на море.)
2. *Как только Аарон, по указанию Моисея, **простер свой жезл над Нилом**, ужасная казнь совершилась — вода в реке превратилась в кровь.*
   (Направил жезл — как? над чем? — над Нилом, над морем.)

Думаю, что приемлемы оба варианта, каждый — своём контексте.

Answer (score 1):

В переводе книги "Магия Древнего Египта. Тайны Книги мертвых" (автор - Эрнест Альфред Уоллис Бадж) встречается такое:

"Он простер свой жезл над водами, и в них закишели жабы; дотронулся жезлом до пыли, и она превратилась в мошек".

Однако в другом примере:

"И простер Моисей жезл свой на землю Египетскую, и
Господь навел на сию землю восточный ветер, продолжавшийся весь тот день и всю ночь".